# Javascript arrow notation functions undefined syntax error

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I am new to javascript, i trying to learn to js, here i am getting syntax error while console the output

```js
const screemwarriors = () => {
  var warriors = "Ninja";
  shootwarriors = function(){
    console.log(warriors);
  }
}
const output = screemwarriors();
console.log(output.shootwarriors());
```

Here i am getting syntax error

Comment: Could you post the error? It's probably because you didn't define `shootwarriors`.

Comment: `shootwarriors: function(){ return console.log(warriors); }` The `:` should be a `=`

Comment: hi @PatrickHollweck, i tried your solution can you pls check the above error

Comment: @VijayaKrishna You said only about the error, didn't say what your code should do. Either way, looking at your comment it seems you want https://jsbin.com/tocahaxuwe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: If you want to return something from the function you have to use the `return` keyword. Add `return shootwarriors;` at the end of the function

Comment: @VijayaKrishna I would recommend you read some good [books](https://eloquentjavascript.net/) to learn JS first..

Comment: You have different code in the post than in the jsbin. Do you know js ? It seems like you should learn js first

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to access the result as an object. You must return the function in an object if you intend to do it in this way.

*Update: cleaned up code*

```js
const screemwarriors = () => ({
  shootwarriors: () => {
    console.log("Ninja");
  }
});

const output = screemwarriors();
output.shootwarriors();
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your calling code will work if you modify your function like this:

```js
const screemwarriors = function() {
  var warriors = 'Ninja';
  return {
    shootwarriors: function() {
      return warriors;
    }
  }
}

const output = screemwarriors();
console.log(output.shootwarriors());
```